# Получение имени определённого окна. Python

Tags: python

Есть код:

```
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow
print(GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow()))
```

Он выдаёт имя активного окна.

Как сделать так, что бы он выдавал имя определённого окна, например аимпа?
Или может быть есть другой способ?

Comment: Что значит определенного? Окно по сути есть объект, предок которого "рабочий стол"...
https://firststeps.ru/mfc/winapi/r.php?1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему так:

```
import psutil #подгружаем библиотеки
import win32gui
import win32process
pid = next(item for item in psutil.process_iter() if item.name() == 'Ваше_приложение.exe').pid #получаем pid нашего exe
def enum_window_callback(hwnd, pid): #разбираем pid на "подпроцессы"
    tid, current_pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
    if pid == current_pid:
        windows.append(hwnd) #добавляем их в массив
windows = []
win32gui.EnumWindows(enum_window_callback, pid)
print([win32gui.GetWindowText(item) for item in windows][0]) #выводим в консоль имя первого окна по его id
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Извините, а почему вы не ответили на комментарий под вашим вопросом?

Comment: @0xdb
я думал что это риторический вопрос